# Text reveal masking on scroll: how to get clip-path: inset() work on IE and Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, clip-path

The following CSS code doesn't work in IE and Edge but working fine in Chrome and Safari and on iOS.

A demo is available here: https://new-css-clip-text-reveal-mask.webflow.io/

Any thoughts how to get it work in IE and Edge?

```
.text-holder {
clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
-webkit-clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have solved it. Two cumulating problems. IE and Edge have some trouble with flexbox (used to center the text element) and IE + Edge can't handle clip-path: inset(). I used clip: rect() instead.

Here is the code and the pen: https://codepen.io/headstarterz/pen/BaaPKMN

```
clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
-webkit-clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
   /* IE10+ CSS */
.text-holder {clip: rect(0,auto,auto,0);}
.text {display: block; width: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 50vh;} 
}

@supports (-ms-accelerator:true) {
   /* Edge 12+ CSS */ 
.text-holder {clip: rect(0,auto,auto,0);}
.text {display: block; width: 100%;text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 50vh;} 
}

@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
    /* Edge 16+ CSS */ 
.text-holder {clip: rect(0,auto,auto,0);}
.text {display: block; width: 100%;  text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 50vh;} 
}
```